# How to pass arguments using java script window.location to a java method in play framework?

Tags: javascript, java, html, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to call a method with parameter in my java file using window.location in javascript. I've tried different approaches but not able to call the function. When I tried to print the value that I've passed it is getting logged in the console but when I tried to call it in the method it is throwing value not found error. What changes I should make to my code to call the method?.

And the call that I've made for getUsers with no arguments is working fine.

And for calling with arguments I tried to take it as a separate string and tried to concat and then assign to window.location even then it hasn't worked. I want to successfully call the method in my controller.

Tried with single quotes, @ and $.

```
<script>
        function displayPopUp(stri) {

                window.location = "@routes.UserController.deleteUser(stri)";


        }
window.location = "@routes.UserController.getUsers()";
    </script>
```

Comment: Will need you to post a bit more code for anyone to be able to assist you.

Comment: <td>
 <button onclick="displayPopUp('@w.username')">Delete User</button>
</td>                                                                                                                                                                  function displayPopUp(stri) {
   var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
   if (r == true) {
    window.location = '@routes.UserController.deleteUser(stri)';
   } else {
    window.location = "@routes.UserController.getUsers()";
                        }                                                                                    }

Comment: Yeah to put some more code I need to enter some more data. no matter how much information I am trying to type it give me an error to enter some more data as your code seems to be more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a short - it is not possible.

The `@routes.UserController.deleteUser(stri)` is compiled on the server, and `function displayPopUp(stri)` is run on the client, so the next code will not work "as expected":

```
<script>
  function displayPopUp(stri) {
    window.location = "@routes.UserController.deleteUser(stri)";
  }
</script>
```

**Solution**

Javascript reverse routing:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaJavascriptRouter
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting

Fast example:

create a javascriptRoutes **action** in a controller :

If you use **Java**:

```
public Result javascriptRoutes() {
  return ok(JavaScriptReverseRouter.create(
          "jsRoutes", routes.javascript.UserController.deleteUser()))
      .as("text/javascript");
}
```

If you use **Scala**:

```
def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(
    JavaScriptReverseRouter("jsRoutes")(
      routes.javascript.UserController.deleteUser
    )
  ).as("text/javascript")
}
```

Add correponding **route**:

```
GET     /javascriptRoutes      controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes
```

Load the **javascript** routers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"></script>
```

Now you can use them in the **client** javascript

```
<script>
  function displayPopUp(stri) {
    window.location = jsRoutes.controllers.UserController.deleteUser(stri).url;
  }
</script>
```