# How to call playframework api with parameters using ajax from jquery without reloading the page?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to load an element in my web application without reloading the entire page using play framework, jquery and ajax. I am not able to call the API with parameters from jquery.
What are the changes that should be done or additional code that should be written to call the API with parameters without reloading the entire page using jquery, ajax and play framework?

Previously I've got the same problem with javascript but I've resolved it. The same thing I've tried applying for it also but it has not worked.

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "@routes.UserController.getUserKeySearch(keySearchForm.get().keySearchText)", success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>


@inputText(keySearchForm("keySearchText"),'_label -> "")
<input type = "button" value = "Click Me" id = "button">
```

I am getting NoSuchElementException for the above code:

[CompletionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the code is running on the server side:

```
url: "@routes.UserController.getUserKeySearch(keySearchForm.get().keySearchText)"
```

So you need to reload the page to get the correct value of the `@routes.UserController.getUserKeySearch(keySearchForm.get().keySearchText)`

The solution is to use the Javascript Router, check my answer to your previous question: [How to pass arguments using java script window.location to a java method in play framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303486/how-to-pass-arguments-using-java-script-window-location-to-a-java-method-in-play/57305778#57305778)

As a result, you will have code like

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  var searchKey = $('#keySearchText').val(); // Selector could be different. 
  var searchUrl = sRoutes.controllers.UserController.getUserKeySearch(searchKey).url;
  $.ajax({url: searchUrl, success: function(result){
    console.log(result);
  }});
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.val()` instead of `.value()`?

Comment: Is there any possibility to assign any value for the elements that we have passed from API to HTML?

Comment: You can use jQuery to assign the resulting values to any HTML element you like. For example `$('#someTextElement').text(result)`

Comment: No that's not what I am asking, here in play if we pass the parameters in javascript that we have got from the backend it won't throw any error while calling the API with parameters. I am just asking you whether we can change the value of such variable in jquery method.

Comment: You got the `NoSuchElementException` because you have an empty form on the server. The string `@routes.UserController.getUserKeySearch(keySearchForm.get().keySearchText)` is running on the server, in the process of generating client code. I guess you suppose that it must run when `$("#button").click` is run but it is not. Remove the "API parameter" then check the client code - you will see that the URL is already present in the client source code.

Comment: The solution is to use the Javascript Router. Playframework will generate the javascript code, so you will be able to get the routes on the client just like you do it on the server.